# Why does Imagemagick produce strange results when converting to WEBP format?

Tags: imagemagick, webp

I was experimenting with JPEG2000 and WEBP through Imagemagick. They were both giving me much better compression levels than I had gotten from JPEG in GIMP, with WEBP doing better than JPEG2000. But when I changed the input image from a JPEG to a PNG, WEBP suddenly started creating output files that were even larger than the input. JPEG2000 showed no significant change. I tried to add options like -format webp and -define webp:lossless=fase, but they didn't help.

Also, my file manager and identify both insist that the resulting file is a PNG and not a WEBP. I later checked and found that the files converted from JPEG were also considered JPEGs, even though they were smaller than the fine-tuned JPEG2000s.

All images had the same quality level of 85. Imagemagick supposedly supports WEBP natively, and I also have libwebp installed. JPEG2000 is being handled by libJasPer.

What is going on?

Comment: Does the filesize increase if you convert the PNG to a JPEG?  It might be that the original PNG achieves a better compression rate.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the PNG was derived from the JPEG I was originally using. Converting it back to JPEG at 85 quality reduces the size by about two thirds.

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using?

Comment: 8:6.7.7.10-2ubuntu4 according to the package, 6.7.7-10 2012-08-17 Q16 according to diplay.

Comment: You could try updating to the latest version(6.8.5-7). According to the [changelog](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) a few improvements regarding Webp format have been made after 6.7.7-10